# fastest way to read huge data file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import, loading

I currently have a huge data file(600 MB) that I want to read and process in matlab. I've written the following code to read it in. But it takes an insane amount of time to read it.

Any possible alternatives? Or faster ways of reading it?

```
D = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %s %s %s %s %s %f %s %f',17000000,'treatAsEmpty',{'NULL'},'delimiter','|','HeaderLines',1,'EmptyValue',NaN);
```

Comment: I'm trying to read everything in one "gulp". Breaking it into pieces and reading it didn't help much either. I tried using some ways of increasing memory too using this[Link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html)

Comment: My question is more finding a faster alternative to `textscan` if it exists!